I get this error for a Text Composable: "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied"
I get this compile error:

None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

This is my code:
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@Composable
fun HeaderText(header: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(text = header, fontSize = 24.dp, modifier = modifier.padding(16.dp))
}

@Composable
fun ParaGrph(paragraph: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(text = paragraph, fontSize = 16.dp, modifier = modifier.padding(16.dp))
}

@Preview(showBackground = true, showSystemUi = true, name = "new preview")
@Composable
fun SamplePreview() {
    HeaderText(header = stringResource(R.string.Header_text))
    ParaGrph(paragraph = "Hello there")
}

I have checked the gradle dependencies:
{ group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3" }

If found this question, but it doesn't answer my problem: Kotlin, Android Studio. "Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match" on Text(...)
The error disappeared when I accidentally change fontSize to sp instead of dp.

You forgot to post the code that produces the error. Please also include the import statements.

Please remove the screenshot of your code and, instead, paste the code as text. Otherwise we will not be able to copy the code and try it out for ourselves.

@Leviathan added the image to the post and code

@Leviathan added the import statemets

I edited your question to be better understandable/readable. Also I replaced sp by dp, otherwise the problem cannot be reproduced. In the future, please try to write cleaner questions in the first place so they must not be heavily edited by others. You can take this as an example how a good question should look like.

The function you are trying to call doesn't exist.
You want to call the Text function with the following parameters:

text: String
fontSize: Dp
modifier: Modifier

There is no function with those parameters. Instead, use the function with these parameters:

text: String
fontSize: TextUnit
modifier: Modifier

To supply a TextUnit object for the fontSize parameter you can use an sp value, like this:
fontSize = 16.sp

See What is the difference between px, dip, dp, and sp? when you are interested why you should use sp for text instead of dp.
